# Excel VBA removes equal sign from formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with vba code. I don't know why, but it removes equal sign in front of formula... Maybe anyone knows how to fix it?

[image]

Here  is full source code of Excel Sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If Not Intersect(c, Range("X:AI")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("H" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("G" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("H" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("G" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If


            Dim frml1 As String
            Dim frml2 As String
            frml1 = "LARGE(X" & c.Row & ":AI" & c.Row & ";1)"
            frml2 = "SMALL(X" & c.Row & ":AI" & c.Row & ";1)"
            Range("AK" & c.Row).Value = "=AVERAGE(X" & c.Row & ":AI" & c.Row & ")"
            Range("AJ" & c.Row).Value = "=" & frml1 & " - " & frml2
        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("AL:AM")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("K" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("J" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("K" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("J" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
        ...
        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("AU:AU")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("Q" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("P" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("Q" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("P" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
        ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("AY:AY")) Is Nothing Then
            If c > Range("T" & c.Row).Value Or c < Range("S" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf c <= Range("T" & c.Row).Value And c >= Range("S" & c.Row).Value Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ";" in your formula instead of ",". Perhaps because your formula is erroring its removing it.

Comment: "," or ";" is a setting in the regional settings. Basically it depends on your language

Comment: Excel separators depend on language... Example, using danish LP in excel, then it's necessary to separate with semi colon, since comma is already used for decimal separation, instead of like in english as a thousand separator.

Comment: Learn something new every day!

Comment: Well you are not wrong @ClintB. When you set a formula through VBA you need to use `,`. If you want to use your local separators, you need to use `.FormulaLocal`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are coding like this in Excel, it is a good idea to be aware of the following:

```
?application.PathSeparator
?application.DecimalSeparator
?Application.International(xlFormula)
```

Write them in the immediate window of the VB Editor, to see your results. Then you may use them in VBA code, which would work lets say both in Germany and in the USA.